# Prevent auto login during boot once

Tags: windows-8.1, login-screen, auto-login

My Windows 8.1 has auto login enabled. Sometimes I need to login with different user. Is it possible to disable auto login during windows once without disabling it globally? because most of all cases I need it.

All that I found in Google and here is to disable it globally but I don't want to disable it globally. I just need to disable it once during windows startup.

May be there are some keyboard shortcuts which I need to press to prevent automatic login?

Comment: Tried holding `Shift` during start up?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to disable just for once
if enabled it would simply login as that user

**How to Disable Windows AutoLogin**

launch Command Prompt > control userpasswords2
[image]

Make sure "user must enter a user name and password to use this computer" is checked

[image]

Comment: I've emphasized in my answer that I don't need to disable it globally. I need to disable it once during windows boot. But you are proposing me to disable it globally after windows is loaded...........

Comment: not possible, if enabled it would simply login as that user, you can simply logout and login in that user

Comment: hmm, during Windows boot I was pressing Shift, Ctrl, F2, F8 and Windows didn't auto login. So one of this buttons can prevent Windows auto login. I'll find out what exact button can do it later...